# How to diagnose unconnectable port from client side?

Tags: networking, firewall, port

I have a machine that can't connect to a certain port number on a server. I've disabled all firewalls and security software. It can connect just fine to 80 and 443, but not 7777.

Is there a tool or utility to diagnose what's causing the failure to connect to this port?

Comment: ISP blocking that port?

Comment: It's possible -- this is on a friend's machine. Is there any way to tell who/what is dropping/blocking the connection?

Comment: I don't think you can find the exact blocking device... a port testing website can give an "open" or "closed" answer. 7777 sounds like a popular one some ISP might want to block, if only because it sounds cool? If it's possible, try using a different port?

Comment: since 7777 port is used  for file transferring through tcp so it wont open eventhough the firewall is disabled.